# How to extract informations of a list of tuples and how to write more than one information per line?

Tags: python, list, file, tuples

I'm wondering how I can resolve this problem... My input is :`[(18.41870765673129, 9.511001141278493), (17.013801776758395, 14.63476877634968)]` and I would like write with informations of tuple, one file like that:

```
18.41870765673129, 9.511001141278493
17.013801776758395, 14.63476877634968
```

I would like have two informations per line.
My script:

```
def write(filename, l):
    with open(filename,"w") as file:
         for i in range(len(l)):
             for j in l[i]:
                 s = str(j)
                 file.write(s)
```

But my script doesn't work because the ouptut is:

```
18.418707656731299.51100114127849317.01380177675839514.63476877634968
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def write(filename, l):
    with open(filename,"w") as file:
         for i,j in l:
             file.write('{}, {}\n'.format(i, j))
```

If you are using Python3.6 or higher, you can change `write` line to:

```
file.write(f'{i}, {j}\n')
```

Comment: No problem, If you find my answer helpful, please check the gray button beside.

Comment: I just suggest to OP avoiding a 'write' name for the function, as file objects have themselves a 'write' method and similarities can get confusing. Try `save` or something else. Also `wt` and `encoding='utf-8'` in the open call help readability and prevent different file treatments on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def write(filename, l):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
         for t in l:
             file.write(', '.join([str(s) for s in t]))
             file.write('\n')
```

Note: it's not necessary to get the length of the list:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
```

just get all tuples inside of l

```
for t in l:
```

The command below takes all parts of the tuple and converts them to string. The strings are then joined.

```
', '.join([str(s) for s in t])
```

Comment: Don't you need a newline character anywhere?

Comment: Yes, needed to add that

Comment: Thank you but I would like a file like that:

Comment: `map(str, t)` instead of `[str(s) for s in t]` will be better

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[i])):
        if j < len(l[i]) - 1:
            s = s + str(l[i][j]) +", "
        else:
            s = s + str(l[i][j]) +"\n"
        file.write(s)
```